# Get session token for Spring boot/security in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We are using spring boot with spring security to implement a querying interface.  What I want to do is to only allow a fixed number of queries per user to run at a time.  Queries may take a long time and users may send repeated requests faster than we can respond.  I want the controller to only ever be calculating a subset request at a time and I'll have to implement some logic as to which requests to respond to.

To do this, I need to know the session token for the given user.  Is there an easy way to get this in the controller's methods?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to get sessionId in controllers you can use
`RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();`

Comment: Ok, and this will remain constant while they are logged in?  Does it matter if they have two windows open from the session?  Is there a way to distinguish that?

Comment: it will be same while a user is logged in also if user opens two windows in same session(same browser).

Answer (score 13):

I find it easier to add the parameter 'HttpSession session' in your request mapping:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/hello")  
public String home(HttpSession session) {  
    String sessionId = session.getId();  
    System.out.println("[session-id]: " + sessionId);  

    ...

    return "anyPage";  
}
```